# How to put table and PNG next to each other in the same figure?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

How can I put a table and a PNG (using `\includegraphics`) next to each other in the same figure, in the following way?

```
             +----+
    +-----+  |png |
    |table|  |png |
    |table|  |png |
    +-----+  +----+
  Figure 4.1: Caption
```

So the table and the PNG are aligned at the bottom.

I tried to just put both in a table (2 columns), but the objects are not aligned at the bottom.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to align the table with its baseline by passing it the optional `[b]` placement argument. After that you can just put them side-by-side. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
  \begin{tabular}[b]{|cc|}
    \hline a & b \\ c & d \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \qquad
  \rule{2cm}{3cm}% = graphic
  \caption{Double figure/table combo!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parbox or minipage.