# How do I put two different pictures side by side?

Tags: floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)

How do I put two different pictures side by side?

I'm using the figure environment.
My code is:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}
\caption{Figura experimental. Nome fase4.pdf}
\label{fase1}
\end{figure}
```

After the response from @flh I tried the code below and failed.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{left}[scale=0.2,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}
\caption{Figura experimental. Nome fase4.pdf}
\label{fase1}
\includegraphics{rigth}[scale=0.2,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}
\caption{Figura experimental. Nome fase4.pdf}
\label{fase2}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have become confused by @lfh's intended meaning of "left" and "right". The following MWE (minimum working example) explains the process in detail. The setup assigns each graphic a width of `0.48\textwidth`; change this setup to meet your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option for production version of file
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase4.pdf}
\caption{Figura experimental}
\label{fase1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill} % it's important not to leave blank lines before and after this command
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{fase5.pdf}
\caption{Altra figura experimental}
\label{fase2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{left}
\includegraphics{right}
\end{figure}
```

This will produce two pictures in the same figure. If you want one figure for each picture, you may need to use two minipages.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/how-to-put-table-and-png-next-to-each-other-in-the-same-figure/3771#3771

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I tried to put the code below. And it did not work. My code: