# Figure and Table next to each other (memoir class)

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, captions

To save space, I would like to place the following table next to each other. Each has a separate caption. I have this,

[image]

I want this,

[image]

Sample code,

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithmicthesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{figure.png}
\caption{This is the caption for figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is the caption for table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & Item 1 \\
3 & Item 2 \\
4 & Item 3 \\
5 & Item 4 \\
5 & Item 5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The solution mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/how-to-put-table-and-png-next-to-each-other-in-the-same-figure) doesn’t allow two captions.

Comment: And another possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62282/21591 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `capt-of` package provides the right solution with `\captionof`. Also  `caption` provides it, but this package is not recommended with `memoir`; on the contrary, the trick performed by `capt-of` is compatible with this class.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % the demo option is just for the example
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.png}
\caption{This is the caption for figure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & Item 1 \\
3 & Item 2 \\
4 & Item 3 \\
5 & Item 4 \\
5 & Item 5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\vspace{0pt}` commands are to ensure top alignment. Dispose of them as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works. \hspace{} can be used instead of \file to fine tune space between columns.

Comment: I didn't even know that the `capt-of` package exists but that was I was looking for. :)

Comment: How can I make the table be placed vertically central to the image please?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your comment, egreg. Now I adjunt an elaborate example:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]\RawFloats
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{figure.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{caption of figure\label{fig06-42a}}
\end{minipage}

\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{caption of table}\label{tab3}
\vspace{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\hline
\rule[-8pt]{0pt}{22pt}$M$& \hspace{20pt}$10 \log_{10}R_{M}$  \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{14pt}8&\hspace{20pt} 1,65 \\
16&\hspace{20pt} 4,20 \\
32&\hspace{20pt} 7,02 \\
64&\hspace{20pt} 9,95 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: @hpsoj626 Thanks for your edition.